# Fannington-Manning power calculation in SAS

Tags: sas, statistics

I'm attempting to compute a Fannington-Manning power calculation in SAS.

I have a proportion of incidence of a disease based on a novel treatment at 15.7%, with the previous standard of care at 18.7%. I want to compute the power based on a non-inferiority margin of 9%; we reject null if upper side of 95% CI on Proportion treatment - Proportion control is less than 9%. The new 'treatment' has 311 patients while the standard of care would have 867.

The null hypothesis:

Null : Proportion treatment ≥ Proportion standard of care + margin
Alternative: Proportion treatment < Proportion standard of care + margin

From my understanding, here is what the code should be:

```
proc power;
twosamplefreq test = fm
refproportion = 0.187
nullproportiondiff = 0.09
proportiondiff = -.03
alpha = .025
sides = L
groupns = (867 311)
power = . ;
run;
```

Based on this code I have a power of 99.6%. Is this correct?

Comment: Shouldn't alpha be 0.05 since you're doing a one sided test, otherwise it's a 97.5% CI.

Comment: And you'll get better responses on communities.sas.com than here for a subject specific topic such as this. Post it in the stats forum.